# MonoGame Phone Testing Errors

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, monogame

I am trying to great a lunar lander like Game using MonoGame with Xna, integrated with Visual Studios 2013 and my end goal is to run this a app on a Windows 8.1 phone. I am encountering some errors. Below is the code that is causing the most problems.

One of the errors I am having is in the Game1.cs file:

```
public class GameStart : Game
{
    ...
}
```

The error I am getting is

> Error 1 Missing partial modifier on declaration of type
>   'GameName1.GameStart'; another partial declaration of
>   this type exists  C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\GameName1\GameName1\GamePage.xaml.cs

**UPDATE**

```
    public GameStart()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        _graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.LandscapeLeft|DisplayOrientation.LandscapeRight;
        _graphics.IsFullScreen = true;

        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        //if (_motion.IsDataValid) //gonna get an error
        //{
        _motion = new Motion();
        //}
        // Frame rate is 30 fps by default for Windows Phone.
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);

        // Extend battery life under lock.
        InactiveSleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        _CurrentState = GameState.Active;

    }
```

Type 'GameName1.GameStart' already defines a member called 'GameStart' with the same parameter types    C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GameName1\GameName1\Game1.cs

Here are both of the classes that this error message is referring to.

```
public GameStart()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _game = XamlGame<Game>.Create("", this);

     // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
     //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
}
```

**Update**

I tired changing XamlGame.Create method to take string instead of "", and it gave me a different error, 
**as a side note this code was auto generated.**

```
public partial class GameStart : Game
{

    private GameStart _game;

    // Constructor
    public GameStart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _game = XamlGame<Game>.Create(string , this);

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }
```

}
I was getting this error with " ":

> Error 3   The best overloaded method match for
>   'MonoGame.Framework.WindowsPhone.XamlGame.Create(string,
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage)' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\GameName1\GameName1\GamePage.xaml.cs

**But**

now I am getting this error: Invalid expression term 'string'

.

Comment: Part of this update is incorrect - passing `string` makes no sense, it is an alias for the **type** - the point is the variable or value you pass there has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

For your class `GameStart`, the error is saying that you need the `partial` modifier on the class.
This is how you tell the compiler that the class definition is split into multiple files (in this case, Game1.cs and GamePage.xaml.cs). See [Partial classes and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Everywhere you have

```
public class GameStart : Game 
{
    ...
}
```

Change it to

```
public partial class GameStart : Game 
{
    ...
}
```

**Update for updated question**

The second error is saying you are passing the incorrect parameters to the `Create` method. The signature

```
MonoGame.Framework.WindowsPhone.XamlGame.Create(string, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage)
```

indicates that the first argument must be of type `string` and the second of type `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage`

You are calling the method like `_game = XamlGame<Game>.Create("", this);`

The first parameter (`""`) is a string, so this is fine.

The second parameter (`this`) refers to the instance of the class being constructed, in this case an instance of the `GameStart` class. The error is telling you that `this` does not have the correct type, namely `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage`.